# How does Keras tokenizer handle unseen data?

Tags: keras, nlp

Say I have trained a tokenizer with some vocabulary, now what exactly does keras tokenizer() do when it encounters a word which was not present in vocabulary(training data)  does it simply ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation if you set the oov_token you should be able to handle unseen words.

```
oov_token`: if given, it will be added to word_index and used
            to replace out-of-vocabulary words during text_to_sequence calls
```